# In css menu bar, list item becomes vanished when move to it?

Tags: html, css

I am working on css menu bar. Everything working fine but when we leave the parent menu then list items of that parent becomes vanished. So please give me exact code to rectify this problem.

Code:

```
 .menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
 }

 .menu li a {
   display: block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 34px;
  }

  .menu ul {
     position: absolute;
     left: -9999px;
     list-style: none;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 1s ease;
 }
  .menu ul li {
     float: none;
     z-index: 100;
     background-color:#FF7F50;
}
  .menu ul a {
     white-space: nowrap;
}

  .menu li:hover ul {
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     left: 5px;
     opacity: 1;
     z-index: 100;
  }

   .menu li:hover ul a {
      box-shadow: none;
      z-index: 100;
 }

 .menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   z-index: 100;
 }
```

Comment: can you post your html too and any other relevant css?

Comment: where is your html and rest of the css?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? The HTML would also be useful.